# R schedule automatic package updates

Tags: r, install.packages, r-taskscheduler

I want to automatically check and update packages every day.
For this purpose, I've written few lines below which runs smoothly when I execute it in my RStudio.

```
options(install.packages.compile.from.source = "always")
update.packages(ask = FALSE, dependencies = TRUE)
```

Then I scheduled this mini script with `taskscheduleR` package to run daily.
The scheduled job is succesfully called to be executed but is being halted and logs the below error:

```
Error in contrib.url(repos, type) : 
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: update.packages -> available.packages -> contrib.url
Execution halted
```

What do I need to add in order to make it execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to specify CRAN mirror:

```
options(repos = c(CRAN = "http://cran.rstudio.com"))
```

Does it work now?